# How to remove_menu_page added by a plugin that appears to have no referenceable slug

Tags: admin-menu

How do I remove a menu page that is added by a plugin like this:

```
add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_menu'));
```

Where there is no slug.  Looking at the plugin code and using the links in the anchors doesn't seem to work:

```
remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=tf_slider_list' );
```

Any suggestions how to remove these links from the menu?  I'm going to be removing it for non-admins, so using it in conjunction with:

```
function custom_remove_menu_pages() {
    remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=tf_slider_list' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_remove_menu_pages', 999 );
```

**Update**

I ended up displaying the global menu, and then using unset() to remove the $menu indexes.  Any reason why I wouldn't do it this way:

```
function custom_remove_menu_pages() {

    global $menu;

    unset($menu[26]);
    unset($menu[27]);
    unset($menu[28]);
    unset($menu[29]);        
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_remove_menu_pages', 999 );
```

Comment: Did you try using 'tf_slider_list' as the arg for remove_menu_page()?  To clarify, you need to examine the 'add_menu' function in the plugin to get the slug, but I believe it should be 'tf_slider_list'.

Comment: Yep, you're right!  Thanks, much cleaner than unset()